# How can I show Google Calendar invites from my alternate email address?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have an alternate email addresses set up in my Google account settings. Now some people frequently sent me Google Meetings using this alternate email address. However, these invites don't show up in my Google Calendar as an invite made directly to my gmail address would.

Is there any way to show these events from my alternate email address in my calendar?

I found some answers on this site about how receive invites on gmail but respond using my alternate email address. I couldn't seem to find advice on what happens if the invite is sent to the alternate email address instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the sidebar of Google Calendar under Other Calendars select the [image] sign giving:

[image]
then "Subscribe to calendar" adding in the email address of the calendar you wish to include.

Comment: If this answers your question, please take a moment to accept it and upvote it in accordance with site guidance so that it can be easily found by others seeking an answer to this or a similar issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping, @User24601! Doing this I'm getting "<myalternateemail> doesn't have a Google Calendar account.", with an option to send an invite to start using Google Calendar. But if I actually try to do that, it would prompt me to create a new Google account. I'd understand this behaviour if it weren't for the fact that this email address is already linked to my Google account ...